Does $\alpha-\alpha^r \in K$ imply $\alpha \in K$?
Let $K$ be a finite extension of the $p$-adic number field $\mathbb{Q}_p$.
Assume two algebraic numbers $\alpha-\alpha^r \in K$ and $p\beta-\beta^{p^r} \in K$, where $r \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha,~\beta$ are integral element.

Does $\alpha \in K$?

Does $\beta \in K$?

When the answers are yes for both cases?



It seems to me that the answer is yes in both cases.
Consider the first case:
$\alpha-\alpha^r \in K \Rightarrow \alpha(1-\alpha^{r-1}) \in K$. If $\alpha \notin K$, $\alpha^{r-1}$ may not belong to $K$ and therefore $\alpha (1-\alpha^{r-1}) \notin K$ in that case, so a contradiction. So $\alpha \in K$.
I am not happy with the above argument. Maybe we can treat $\alpha$ here as a $(r-1)$th root of unity and we note that $K$ may not contain all roots of unity.
The same argument applies for second case.
Edit: Much later, I realised that I should give more clarification. My $\alpha$ is a root of unity while my $\beta$ satisfies $\beta^m=p^n$, where $m,n \in \mathbb N$. Although I repeatedly mentioned it throughout my comments or even in my primary effort. However, this edit doesn't apply to the answer given below.

Suppose that $p$ is any prime, that $K$ is any finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$, and $r > 1$ any integer. Then there exists an element $\alpha$ which is:

algebraic over $K$ and so over $\mathbf{Q}_p$,
integral (has non-negative valuation),
satisfies $\alpha^r - \alpha \in K$,
does not lie in $K$; $\alpha \notin K$.

Similarly, for any $p$ and any $K$ and any $r > 0$, there exists an element $\beta$ which is:

algebraic over $K$ and so over $\mathbf{Q}_p$,
is integral,
satisfies $\beta^{p^r} - p \beta \in K$,
does not lie in $K$.

The proofs are similar. First, the case of $\beta$. Let $\pi$ be a uniformizer of $K$. Let $\beta$ be any root of the Eisenstein polynomial:
$$x^{p^r} - p x - \pi = 0.$$
Then:

$\beta$ is algebraic over $K$, and so is algebraic over $\mathbf{Q}_p$,
$\beta$ is integral; if $v(\pi) = 1$ then $v(\beta) = p^{-r}$.
$\beta^{p^r} - p \beta = \pi$ and $\pi \in K$ by construction.
$\beta$ is not in $K$ because the valuation of $\beta$ is not an integer. In fact the polynomial $x^{p^r} - p x - \pi = 0$ is Eisenstein so $K(\beta)$ has degree $p^r$ over $K$.

Now $\alpha$. Let $A$ be the ring of integers of $K$, and let $\pi$ be a uniformizer. Let $k = A/\pi$ be the residue field. The polynomial $\varphi(z) = z-z^r$ gives a map $k \rightarrow k$ by evaluation, that is, send $x \in k$ to $\varphi(x) = x-x^r \in k$. Since $k$ is finite, this map is surjective if and only if it is injective. Since $\varphi(0)=\varphi(1)$, $\varphi$ is not injective so it is not surjective. Therefore there exists a $y \in k$ such that $y$ is not of the form $z - z^r$ for $z \in k$. Let $\gamma \in A$ be any element which is $y \bmod \pi$, and let $\alpha$ be any root of
$$x - x^r = \gamma.$$
Then:

$\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$, so is algebraic over $\mathbf{Q}_p$.
$\alpha$ is integral, in fact $v(\alpha)=0$ since $v(\gamma) = 0$ (as $y \ne 0$).
$\alpha - \alpha^r = \gamma \in A \subset K$ by construction.
If $\alpha \in K$ then $\alpha \in A$. But then if $z = \alpha \bmod \pi$, then

$$z - z^r \equiv \alpha - \alpha^r = \gamma \equiv y \bmod \pi,$$
and so $z-z^r = y$ in $k$. By construction there is no such $z$.
Remark This answer was already given in the comments. The OP is unable or unwilling to try to understand it, so I will make it community wiki and then I will personally avoid any future interaction on this question.
